# jquery autocomplete to fill in another field

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete on one input field to fill in another:

```
<input id='fruit' name='fruit' type='text'>
<input id='details' name='details' type='text'>
```

jQuery code:

```
var x = ["apple", "kiwi", "lemon"];

$( "#fruit" ).autocomplete({
     source: x
});

jQuery(document).on("change","#fruit", function()
{
    $.each(x, function(key, value) {

        switch(value) {
            case "apple":
                $('#details').val("Delicious");
                break;
            case "kiwi":
                $('#details').val("Yummy");
                break;
            case "lemon":
                $('#details').val("Sour");

        }
    });
});
```

When someone selects apple, kiwi or lemon with the autocomplete then it fills out the other input field with the corresponding text.

I have two issues:

1. Currently it always prints out "Sour"
2. When you select an entry from the autocomplete you have to click away again to fill out the field. Is there a way to do this when someone selects a choice from autocomplete?

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTE77/4/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you get things bit hard using switch. If you take a look over ui documentaton you will see that you can use array of objects. If i were you i would put the source like this :

```
var x = [
    { label : 'apple', value : 'Delicious' },
    { label : 'kiwi', value : 'Yummy' },
    { label : 'kiwiooo', value : 'aaa' },
    { label :  'lemon', value : 'Sour' }
];
```

Now you know that for a certain label you have a certain value, without using switch and other stuff, so the rest of code will looks like

```
$( "#fruit" ).autocomplete({
    source: x,
    focus : function(){ return false; }
})
.on( 'autocompleteresponse autocompleteselect', function( e, ui ){
  var t = $(this),
      details = $('#details'),
      label = ( e.type == 'autocompleteresponse' ? ui.content[0].label :  ui.item.label ),
      value = ( e.type == 'autocompleteresponse' ? ui.content[0].value : ui.item.value );

  t.val( label );
  details.val( value );

  return false;
});
```

I put return false on `focus` because if the user choose to slide down on list with keyboard arrows, in `#fruit` input will appear the value and this is not ok.

You can play with stuff [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/GTE77/5/)

Comment: I like the idea of using an array of objects. However the advantage of a switch statement is that I can use `case: apple case: lemon` in one line with one value. I have many cases of this. Is there a way to do this other than duplicating the value in the array of objects.

Comment: I ended up using this. I removed `autocompleteresponse` as one of the selectors as you get strange behavior otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need or want the each loop inside the change handler. Just use the value of your input.

```
$(document).on("change","#fruit", function()
{
    switch($('#fruit').val()) {
        case "apple":
            $('#details').val("Delicious");
            break;
        case "kiwi":
            $('#details').val("Yummy");
            break;
        case "lemon":
            $('#details').val("Sour");

    }
});
```

This code could be improved by not performing the `$('#fruit')` on each invocation of the handler, but it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autocomplete's change:

```
$('#fruits').autoceomplete({ source: x,
change: function (event, ui) {
        switch(ui.item){
              case 'apple': break;
              case 'kiwi': break;
        }
}})
```

Comment: Seems simple but that doesn't work (even if I fix the obvious errors)