# How to use jQuery-ui Autocomplete to fill two input fields?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201730/jquery-autocomplete-to-fill-in-another-field) was my model to solve my problem. Its 'source' value looks like this;

```
var x = [
    { label : 'apple', value : 'Delicious' },
    { label : 'kiwi', value : 'Yummy' },
    { label : 'kiwiooo', value : 'aaa' },
    { label :  'lemon', value : 'Sour' }
];
```

I think the problem is I don't have the output from my MySQL query formatted correctly. Both of my input's are receiving the same value, which in this case is the cs1 value. 
The query itself works fine but here is my MySQL/PHP can anyone tell me what I've messed up?

```
    if (trim(strip_tags(isset($_GET['term'])))){
        $return_cs1 = array();
        $return_Fname = array();

    try {

    $stmt = $db_found->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        callsign as cs1,
        Fname
      FROM NetLog 
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT max(recordID) as recordID
          FROM NetLog 
         WHERE callsign LIKE  :term
         GROUP BY callsign
      ) t1 on t1.recordID = NetLog.recordID;");    

    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_cs1[] = $row["cs1"];
            $return_Fname[] = $row["Fname"];
        array_push($return_cs1, $return_Fname);
        }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

    echo json_encode($return_cs1);  
    flush();
} // End of isset
```

Comment: where is the js?

Comment: What contains `$row["cs1"]` and `$row["Fname"]`? How to you create your JSON?

Comment: I've adjusted to show the entire MySQL.

Comment: `isset($_GET['term'])` returns a boolean, not a string. So `strip_tags` and `trim()` doesn't make sens.

Comment: You may be correct @Syscall but thats not the issue anyway. How can I see the actual value of 'term'?

Comment: Use just `if (isset($_GET['term'])){ $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));` Your question is unclear to me. What do you want to push into what please?

Comment: @Syscall I was just curious how I can see the value of 'term' when it gets to my PHP/MySQL script. After the if (isset($_GET['term'])) stuff.